# QGIS equivalent to Mapinfo SQL qery

Tags: qgis, sql

To run a simple interest query in Mapinfo I would use

```
Select * from _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map, Carpentaria_Shire where _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map.Obj Intersects Carpentaria_Shire.Obj into Selection
```

In QGIS in Add--Virtual Layer and in DB Manager I keep getting errors

```
select * from _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map where st_intersects (_1_10000_map_sheet_key_map.geometry, Carpentaria_Shire.geometry) as Selection
```

gives the following error

> Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS select * from
>   _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map where st_intersects (_1_10000_map_sheet_key_map.geometry, Carpentaria_Shire.geometry) as
>   Selection: 1 - near "as": syntax error

The same from Virtual Layers and trying to use geom_from_wkt I get

> Query preparation error on PRAGMA table_info(_tview): no such column:
>   Carpentaria_Shire.geom_from_wkt

What's the expected structure of the query in QGIS SQL implementation?

Additionally can this be done in the Advanced Filter expression?

Comment: PS I know I can do this very easily in QGIS--Vector--Research--Select by location but I want to get more familiar with the Virtual Layer queries in QGIS.

Comment: Please do not comment on your own question.  Instead [Edit] to make clarifications.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SQL Select was one of the few things I missed about MapInfo when my work changed to QGIS.

You need to include the table `"Carpentaria_Shire"` in the `FROM` clause. Try this:

```sql
select A.*
from _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map AS A, Carpentaria_Shire as B
where st_intersects(A.geometry, B.geometry)
```

or for a different syntax:

```sql
SELECT A.*
FROM _1_10000_map_sheet_key_map AS A
JOIN Carpentaria_Shire AS B ON st_intersects(A.geometry, B.geometry)
```

To do it as an advanced filter expression:

```py
intersects($geometry, aggregate('Carpentaria_Shire', 'collect', $geometry))
```

Comment: Brilliant - as to the 2nd part of my question. Is this possible to do using the Expression based filter on a table? I tried using the Map_Layer attributes but it doesn't work - 'Carpentaria_Shire_540e7bd7_f775_4e8e_8e96_61f2dcbe36bb' intersects 'Grid_3bbf8f0c_9cdb_453b_8a92_784f328945ee'

Comment: Try:`intersects($geometry,aggregate('Carpentaria_Shire','collect',$geometry))`

Comment: Works perfectly -thank you.